# English-speaking kollels in Yerushalayim

Tags: product-recommendation, english, yeshiva-school

I am looking for an English-speaking kollel for either morning or afternoon anywhere in Yerushalayim for a bright, young married American with a YU yeshiva background. He is not particular about the subject matter being studied or the orthodox affiliation of the kollel, but he wants a serious learning environment where he can advance in his Torah learning and growth. Due to other commitments, he is only available to learn one seder daily at this time. Any recommendations would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Which area were you thinking of? Also, can you elaborate on your yeshiva background?

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_College_of_Technology

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Moshe and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You want big? Small? Charedi? Dati Leumi? Kodshim? Halacha? Kiruv/chinuch training?

Comment: This a great place: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jerusalem_Kollel